# Remove values from one list if they appear in another

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a list of records in Access. I'm trying to filter one set of values [A] by a condition on another set of values [B]. I want to retrieve values [A] where where the corresponding value [B] is a certain value, and filter out any value [A]s where a record with anything but a particular value [B] exists.

For example, I might want to retrieve [A]s where the sole value for [B] is '5'. If two records exist with the same value for [A], one having a [B] value of '5' and one having a [B] value of '7', both records should be excluded. If two records exist with the same value for [A], and both have a value of '5' for [B], they should be included.

In the list below, I might want to retrieve [A] values where all [B] values equal 65. So I'd want the query to return TFL, but not MCA, even though it has a 65, because it also has a non-65 (72).

**A | B**

MCA | 65

MCA | 72

TFL | 65

PKO | 72

PKO | 89

I've got as far as get a list of [A]s with a particular value [B], and a list of [A]s with any other value [B]. I was thinking I could then take out from the first list any value [A]s that appear in the second list. In the example above the first list would contain 'MCA' and 'TFL' if I filtered by '65', and the second list would contain 'MCA' and 'PKO'; if I then took out values that appear in the second list from the first list I'd be left with just 'TFL', which is what I want. However, I have no idea how to subtract from one list any values that appear in another list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided a good description of what you want, we just need to translate it into SQL

```sql
SELECT A FROM AndysData WHERE B=65
```

will give you a list of all of the A's where at least one B value is 65.

```sql
SELECT A FROM AndysData WHERE B<>65
```

will give you a list of all the A's that have a B value that is not 65.

To exclude the second batch from the first can be done with a NOT IN clause and a subquery:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM AndysData
WHERE
    B=65
    AND 
    A NOT IN (SELECT A FROM AndysData WHERE B<>65)
```